# python - how should i write the correct SQL statement with raw_input

Tags: python, mysql

Basically is user inputs plot id, I can check whether the plot id exists in the database.

Please help me improve the code. Thanks

```
import MySQLdb
myConn = MySQLdb.connect("rds-mysql..........rds.amazonaws.com", "user", "", "db1")    
print myConn    
print("myConn Established!")    
B_cur = myConn.cursor()    
plot = raw_input("Enter plot ID: ")   
sql = "SELECT * FROM mydb.Plot WHERE plot_id= %s"    
result = B_cur.execute(sql,(plot))
print result.rowcount
```

Error msg is:

```
File "myConn.py", line 16, in <module>
result = B_cur.execute(sql,(plot))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 210, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `(sql,(plot))` format, you can use `format`  directly as below.

**Code:**

```
plot = raw_input("Enter plot ID: ")

sql = "SELECT * FROM mydb.Plot WHERE plot_id= %s"
query= sql,(plot)
print "Your query looks like --"
print query
print "--------------------------------------"
sql = "SELECT * FROM mydb.Plot WHERE plot_id = '{0}'"
query=sql.format(str(plot))
print "My query looks like --"
print query
```

**Output:**

```
Enter plot ID: 123
Your query looks like --
('SELECT * FROM mydb.Plot WHERE plot_id= %s', '123')
--------------------------------------
My query looks like --
SELECT * FROM mydb.Plot WHERE plot_id = '123'
```

Once query is created using `format`, then can be executed

```
result = B_cur.execute(query)
```